# How to migrate from old dojo require to the new dojo AMD loader?

Tags: dojo, require, amd, migrate

i want to migrate from the old dojo.require loader to the new AMD loader so i changed this:

```
        dojo.require("dojo._base.xhr");
        dojo.require("dojox.mobile.parser");
        dojo.require("dojox.mobile");
        dojo.require("dojox.mobile.ScrollableView");
        dojo.require("dojox.mobile.TabBar");
        dojo.require("dojox.mobile.TextBox");
        dojo.require("dojox.mobile.compat");
        dojo.require("dojox.mobile.deviceTheme");
        dojo.require("dojox.mobile.TabBarButton");
        dojo.require("dojox.mobile.View");
        dojo.require("dojox.mobile.Button");
        dojo.require("dojox.mobile.Switch");
        dojo.require("dojo.on");
        dojo.require("dijit.registry");
        dojo.require("dojo.aspect");
        dojo.require("dojo.ready");
        dojo.require("dojox.mobile.ListItem");
        dojo.require("dojo.dom");
        dojo.require("dojo.request");
        dojo.require("dojo.dom-construct");
        dojo.require("dojo.domReady!");
CODE
```

to this:

```
require(["dojo/_base/xhr","dojox/mobile/parser","dojox/mobile","dojox/mobile/ScrollableView","dojox/mobile/TabBar","dojox/mobile/TextBox","dojox/mobile/compat","dojox/mobile/deviceTheme","dojox/mobile/TabBarButton","dojox/mobile/View","dojox/mobile/Button","dojox/mobile/Switch","dojo/on","dijit/registry","dojo/aspect","dojo/ready","dojox/mobile.ListItem","dojo/dom","dojo/request","dojo/dom-construct","dojo/domReady!"],
    function(xhr,parser,mobile,ScrollableView,TabBar,TextBox,compat,deviceTheme,TabBarButton,View,Button,Switch,on,registry,aspect,ready,ListItem,dom,request){CODE})
```

is that the way to do it right?
i have a few other script files that i simple loaded with  How to handle them with the new AMD loader?

I am pretty new to all the programming stuff so please be soft on me :)

Comment: Looks fine to me. There are more detailed instructions here - http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/releasenotes/migration-2.0.html. The final test is ... does it work?! I also think this is the new way for XHR - http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/request/xhr.html#dojo-request-xhr.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to the brand new converter from sitepen. Read about it here : http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2013/04/03/introducing-dojo-amd-converter/

Comment: I haven't used this converter but this looks very handy at least as a starting point.  Your require conversion is correct although the important thing to consider is using the variables created in the new AMD loader.  In General you shouldn't have any "dojo."'s or "dijit."'s in your code.  So 'dojo.byId(node)' would become 'dom.byId(node)'.  The converter appears to handle these conversions.